# Compose Multiplatform GIF

Tags: gif, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm trying to create a compose multiplatform application for Android and iOS. At the moment I am faced with the problem of adding GIFs or lottie animations, because the compose itself does not support adding GIFs and there are no libraries that could help with adding GIFs
Maybe someone has encountered this and knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/153

Comment: Thanks @gavr , the first thing I did was look at the JetBrains issues, but it doesn't work for me